# C++ Macro riddle: Printing the name of the TYPE

Tags: c++

In a macro I can use xxxx_##TYPE and ##TYPE##_xxxxx to have the TYPE name filled in correctly, but I can't use ##TYPE## in the middle of a string e.g. (print "##TYPE## is the name of the type";)

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by combining two features. One is ''stringification'', whereby a macro argument is converted to a string by prefixing it with `#`. (This is related to, but different from, the ''token-pasting'' operator `##` that you're obviously already familiar with.) The other is the fact that C++, when given multiple string literals in a row, will combine them into a single string. For example, `"a" "b" "c"` is equivalent to `"abc"`. I'm not clear on exactly how your macro is to be defined, so I can't show you *exactly* what to type, but a full explanation and some good working examples are at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html.

---

**Edited to add** a simple example, at Kleist's request. This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT_WHAT_THE_NAME_OF_THE_TYPE_IS(TYPE) \
  printf("%s\n", "'" #TYPE "' is the name of the type.")

int main()
{
  PRINT_WHAT_THE_NAME_OF_THE_TYPE_IS(Mr. John Q. Type);

  return 0;
}
```

will print this:

```
'Mr. John Q. Type' is the name of the type.
```

(This will run in either C or C++. The reason I wrote it C-ishly is that in my experience these sorts of preprocessor tricks are more common in C code than in real C++ code; but if you wanted to use `std::cout <<` instead of `printf`, you absolutely could.)

Comment: Why not add a simple example, even though you don't know exactly how he'd use it? Could be `#define TYPESTRING(TYPE) "String with typename: " #TYPE " right in the middle."` for example.

Comment: @Kleist: O.K., done. I'm not convinced that it's more useful than the link to the GCC documentation, but it certainly won't hurt. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`##` is the [token pasting operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y.aspx) and it takes two different tokens and pastes them together to make a single token. The entire string literal is considered a single token, thus the pasting operator doesn't work within it. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/cpp/Tokenization.html

Comment: True, but you don't answer his question.

Comment: @Kleist because I couldn't improve on ruakh's answer - I already gave my +1. I just thought this was important background information that needed to be out there.

Answer (score 0):

String literals will be concatenated when they are next to each other.

```
#define QUOTE(X) #X

#define DOSTUFF(TYPE) \
    void print_ ## TYPE () { \
        static const char *str = QUOTE(TYPE) " is the name of the type\n"; \
        printf(str); \
    }

DOSTUFF(Foo);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    print_Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Output of `g++ -E -c main.cpp` will show you what this gets preprocessed into.

```
# 16 "main.cpp"
void print_Foo () { 
  static const char *str = "Foo" " is the name of the type\n"; 
  printf(str); 
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
 print_Foo();
 return 0;
}
```